# Dynamically generated table displayed with errors

Tags: javascript, css, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display correctly a table using bootstrap classes. This table is being generated dynamically from a json file.

The problem is that, when I use the tools to inspect the elements, even though they are displayed in a table, they don't get the bootstrap classes because those properties are closing before I want. Here's my code:

```
      // Makes the request to searches @ Reddit using the Reddit API
  $.getJSON(
    "http://www.reddit.com/r/entrepreneur/search.json?q=" + searchString + "&sort=hot",
    function foo(data)
    {
      //Initializes the table   
        $("#reddit-content").append( '<table class="table table-striped">' );

        $("#reddit-content").append('<thead>');
        $("#reddit-content").append('<tr>');
        $("#reddit-content").append('<th>Title</th>');
        $("#reddit-content").append('<th>Ups</th>');
        $("#reddit-content").append('<th>Downs</th>');
        $("#reddit-content").append('<th>Date</th>');
        $("#reddit-content").append('<th>Visit</th>');
        $("#reddit-content").append('</tr>');
        $("#reddit-content").append('</thead>');
        $("#reddit-content").append('<tbody>');
    
      $.each(
        data.data.children.slice(0, 25),
        function (i, post) {
        
        // create a new javascript Date object based on the timestamp
        // multiplied by 1000 so that the argument is in milliseconds, not seconds
        var date = new Date( post.data.created_utc * 1000 );
        // hours part from the timestamp
        var hours = date.getHours();
        // minutes part from the timestamp
        var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
        // seconds part from the timestamp
        var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
        // Formats the date object for proper viasualization
        var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(minutes.length-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(seconds.length-2);

          $("#reddit-content").append('<tr>');
          $("#reddit-content").append( '<td>' + post.data.title + '</td>');
          $("#reddit-content").append( '<td>' + post.data.ups + '</td>');
          $("#reddit-content").append( '<td>' + post.data.downs + '</td>');
          $("#reddit-content").append( '<td>' + formattedTime + '</td>');
          $("#reddit-content").append( '<td>' + post.data.permalink + '</td>');
          $("#reddit-content").append('</tr>');
        }
      )
      //Ends the table
      $("#reddit-content").append('</tbody>');
      $("#reddit-content").append( '</table>' );
    }
  )
```

And in the following image you can see that the  tag is closing right after it is opened, and this way I cannot apply the bootstrap CSS to it.

[image]

Any idea on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: See MDN for document.createElement("TABLE"), HTMLTableElement.insertRow, HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell and stop using <th> when generating tables automatically for cross browser compatibility, specially old browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending to `$("#reddit-content")` only. You need to append the content to the corresponding parent. Something like this:

```
var $table = $("#reddit-content").append( '<table class="table table-striped">' );
$table.append('<thead><tr><th>...</thead>');
$table.append('<tr>..</tr>');
        :
```

Comment: Great, I now understand, thanks a lot. The problems was in my interpretation of append, which wasn't correct.